# Apache reverse proxy https config leads to 503 error

Tags: apache, https, reverse-proxy

Hope someone can point me in the right direction. I've been trying to get this to work for many hours :(

Scenario - I have a DMZ where I've set up the Apache server. I need to securely talk to the internal server where I have set up another Apache server which is reverse proxied again to a localhost app within the server.. So, basically..

outside world > internet (https://app1.com) > dmz (apache reverse proxy) > internal server (apache reverse proxy - https://app1prod.com) > (http) > localhost:8080

Now, in dmz, I can directly access https://app1prod.com without issues. But, I can't for the life of me get https://app1.com to work from dmz. I get a '503 service unavailable' message :( Here is my apache config in dmz..

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName              app1.com
ProxyRequests           off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName   off
SSLProxyVerify          none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN     off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
LogLevel                debug   
SSLEngine               on
SSLProxyEngine          on  
SSLCertificateFile      "xxx/cert.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile   "xxx/key.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "xxx/certchain.crt"     
ProxyPass               /   https://app1prod.com/
ProxyPassReverse        /   https://app1prod.com/  
<Proxy *>
    order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPreserveHost       on
ProxyTimeout            1200
</VirtualHost>
```

On my httpd.conf, I have the following modules loaded in addition to the defaults..

```
mod_proxy.so
mod_proxy_connect.so
mod_proxy_http.so
mod_ssl
mod_rewrite.so
mod_socache_shmcb.so
mod_ssl.so
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help! Thanks a lot..

Comment: you need to look into error.log

Comment: I did.. Not much help. It looks like it attempts to connect but the next second, it disconnects!     [proxy:debug] [pid 6644:tid 1016] [remote <internal server>]  https: connection complete to <internal server ip:443] (app1prod.com:443)
    [ssl:info] [pid 6644:tid 1016] [remote <internal server>]   Connection to child 0 established (server app1.com:443)
    [proxy:debug] [pid 6644:tid 1016] proxy_util.c(2175):   https: has released connection for (app1prod.com)
    [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 6644:tid 1016] mod_socache_shmcb.c(555):   socache_shmcb_remove (0x4e -> subcache 14)

Comment: From app1.com apache server's shell, can you connect with `curl -v https://app1prod.com/`?

Comment: Pardon me. I'm really new to this. I'm on windows server and have no idea how to use this curl command.. Any pointers? Thanks so much for trying to help me out!

Comment: Just type it exactly like that in command prompt (you can download curl from here https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win64)

Comment: I installed curl for windows and right now since i'm using self signed cert, i get a SSL cert problem - self signed cert in cert chain message!

Comment: Actually, adding -v to the command connects to the app1prod.com port 443!!

Comment: what is the exact apache version?

Comment: I have the latest one.. 2.4.

Comment: If you open a browser on app1.com, can you browse through https://app1prod.com/?

Comment: Yes. I can! No issues. Only app1.com gives me the darn 503 service unavailable message :(

Comment: Does removing `ProxyPreserveHost       on` maybe help?

Comment: OMG!! THANK YOU!! Yes. I commented out that line and restarted the service and it worked.. I can't believe I sat on this issue for 12+ hours without trying it. I owe you a beer.. Thank you so much. As you can tell, it is my first time messing with apache. I have to read up on what this proxypreservehost does! Thanks again Dusan!

Answer (score 5):

Try removing `ProxyPreserveHost on`.

With that directive enabled, the proxied requests will be send to server defined in `ProxyPass` directive, but the HTTP `Host:` header will be preserved from initial request. In your case, the requests sent by Apache to `app1prod.com` will have `Host: app1.com` header, and `app1prod.com` i not configured (probably deliberately) to respond to such request.

Comment: Thanks a million again for the solution and the explanation. You rock. It recorded my upvote but won't show up because I have only less than 15 points (can you tell that I'm not a developer? lol). Thank you..

Comment: Welcome to SO djayrox!